# How to end the app from an activity with the back pressed and not return to the previous activity

Tags: android

I have a problem that has me stuck, I have a webview that shows a page, what I am doing is that before I load the webview it shows me a splashscreen, the problem I have is that when I give the back pressed instead of closing the app, it returns me to the splashscreen and I don't want that, I want the whole app to close when I press backpressed and not return to a previous activity

Comment: Call finish() on the splash page

Comment: Where would that code go?

In the splash screen code I have this

[link]( https://prnt.sc/1smk1cf)

Comment: Back when Google was right about things, they used to strongly discourage having a splash screen at all. Not sure if they still do; I know they basically did a 180 on their formerly great guidelines for icons.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede I agree mostly, but breaking rules is ok if it's because of a choice instead of just not knowing your options. Like the material style guides say to only use bottomnavigationviews for navigation shared across multiple top-level pages. But they're attractive and less intrusive than FABs, so within moderation I use them instead. No one's gonna die. Splash pages? Generally a huge waste of time. But if you finish() them with a callback from a resource you're loading instead of with a timer, then it's not so bad. More attractive than a progressbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put finish() immediately after startActivity(intent).